# jQuery runtime ready event after loading another page

Tags: jquery, events, document-ready

```
var x = $("<div ></div>");
$('body').append(x);
x.load('page.html'
    , function() {
        $(document).ready(
            function (){
            //useful stuff here;
            }
        );  
    });
```

I'm expecting the ready callback function to be executed after the page.html is fully loaded and already executed all it's scripts inside my "div".
This example works. 
My question is: Is this the right way to do what I'm expecting? Is there any other way?
What's the logic behind the ready event in this case? Should it be applied on "document", "this" or "x"?

Comment: Why? `x.load('page.html', function(){//dostuff});` has any issues?

Comment: works fine when you hope execute script after execute ready  on ready() of page.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***dummy.html***

```
<SCRIPT>
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            var x = $("<div >hola</div>");
            $('body').append(x);
            x.load('dummy2.html', function() {

                console.log('dummy callback');

                $(document).ready(
                    function (){
                    console.log('dummy has loaded after dummy2 has loaded');
                    //useful stuff here;
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    );
</SCRIPT>
```

***dummy2.html***

```
 <SCRIPT>
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            console.log('dummy 2a has load');
        }
    );
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            console.log('dummy 2b has load');
        }
    );


</SCRIPT>
```

This example shows how to works the sequence, first print dummy callback', second: dummy 2a and dummy 2b, and the last print is 'dumy has loaded after dummy has loaded', i do know why works ok, but the sequence works OK.

***Update***

if you remove the line $(document).ready the sequence is

first: dummy callback
second: dummy has loaded... /*Wrong!*/

Answer (score 2):

You load event should be encased in `DOM` ready ..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = $("<div ></div>");
    $('body').append(x);
    x.load('page.html', function () {

        //useful stuff here;
    });
});
```

No need for the callback to be enclosed in `DOM ready` handler..

It works in this case as you **do not seem to select any already existing element** on the page. So it will work fine event without the `DOM ready` handler

Comment: if you want execute script before jquery script on page.html works ok, but if you want execute after jquery script $(document)ready(...) of page.html you example no works fine.

Comment: @Sushanth My "useful stuff" should be executed after all scripts in page.html finished running. When the load callback is used, as in your example, it will start running before the scripts in page.html. That's not what I was expecting.